# Detecting patterns in a string in JavaScript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

Given an pattern by a user, such as `[h][a-z][gho]`, and a string *"gkfhxhk"* I'm trying to see if the string contains the pattern.

The pattern means that the first letter would be *'h'*, the next letter can be any letter from `a-z`, and the 3rd letter can be either *'g'* or *'h'* or *'o'*. This is supposed to work for any pattern. So another pattern could be `[y][b-f][jm]`.

First I tried to use nested for loops to create a list of all possible strings but that didn't work. Then I tried using RegExp where I pass in  the pattern but I'm not quite sure if I'm approaching that the right way:

```
let string = "gkfhxhk";
// pattern [h][a-z][gho]

let re = new RegExp('ha-zg|h');

let result  = re.match(re);
```

This just returns a `null` in the result. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You need to use proper reg ex syntax: `/^h[a-z][g|h|o]$/` should do the trick.

Comment: @ChrisG: Why are you puting pipe in the character class? OP doesn't want to match pipe.

Comment: Also the anchors are not needed as OP is willing to match pattern anywhere in string not just the complete string

Comment: @ChrisG The pattern given by the OP is valid regex, although putting a single character within a character set is admittedly a bit awkward.

Comment: Just put your pattern in the regex constructor: `let re = new RegExp('h[a-z][gho]');` or `let re = /h[a-z][gho]/;`

Comment: I should've checked but was too lazy. Yes, its `/h[a-z][hgo]/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the type of problem regex was designed to solve. Your syntax is just wrong. [This site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is an excellent resource for learning regex. As for this specific example, the pattern you want is `h[a-z][gho]`. (The form `[h][a-z][gho]` works as well, but the brackets around `h` are unnecessary.) And in JavaScript, a regex pattern is a special literal, written with `//` instead of `""`.

```js
var re = /h[a-z][gho]/;

var str1 = "gkfhxhk";

var str2 = "gkajflh";

console.log(str1.match(re));

console.log(str2.match(re));
```

Note that `match` returns a list of matches, not a simple true/false value. It returns `null` when there are no matches.

Comment: Why do you anchor the regex?

Comment: @Toto From the question: "The pattern means that the first letter would be 'h'".

Comment: The first letter of the pattern, not of the string!

Comment: I like using `/regex/.test('string')` because it does return a true/false value which I find a bit easier to reason about than `match`. :)